# why data erases while navigating form nsobject class to Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently working in a project in which I want to navigate from a NSObject class to a ViewController, I have successfully navigated to the ViewController but I have saved some data in NSUserDefault in that particular ViewController all the datas has become NULL , Can any one help why the datas have lost

Codes I have used for Navigation:

```
 case ENDED:
        {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
                UIWindow *window=[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
                UIViewController *root = [window rootViewController]; 
                UIStoryboard *storyboard = root.storyboard;
                myTappointmentInfo *vcc =(myTappointmentInfo *) [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"home"];
                [root presentModalViewController:vcc animated:YES];   
            });
            break;
        }
```

these data i got from previous viecontroller while navigation

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recDic forKey:@"dictionaryKey"]; 
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:recRowClick forKey:@"recUDclick"]; 

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Show the code where you set the User-default data

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recDic forKey:@"dictionaryKey"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:recRowClick forKey:@"recUDclick"];
   
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];  these data i got from previous viecontroller while navigation

Comment: Always add the requested code/content in question description, not in comments section.

Comment: don't add code in comment!

Comment: what do you mean by nsobject class to Viewcontroller ??? not getting your question properly!

Comment: Lion from a NSobject class in a particular case ENDED I have to navigate to another viewController, Got it